# show if the parametrized curve is regular

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm trying to show if a curve is regular or not

I know at first we have to find its derivative and check if it is equal to zero or not

if it is equal to zero then its not regular

For example

let says the curve is r(x)=cosx, sinx were [0,pi]

r'(x)=-sinx,cosx
at x=0 r'(0)=0,1 
not regular
is this way correct or do I have to add both such that at x=0 r'(0)=0+1=1

Thanks

Comment: No need Just figured it out

Answer (score 2):

If you have ${\bf r}: I \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^n$, check that $\|{\bf r}'(t)\|^2\neq 0$ for all $t \in I$. This is because ${\bf r}'(t) = {\bf 0} \iff \|{\bf r}'(t)\|^2 = 0$. In your example: $${\bf r}(x) = (\cos x, \sin x) \implies {\bf r}'(x) = (-\sin x,\cos x )\implies \|{\bf r}'(x)\|^2 = 1 \neq 0, \quad \forall \ x \in [0,\pi],$$ so the conclusion is that ${\bf r}$ is regular.